# Have problem understanding translating the camera in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am having trouble about understand the translate the camera. I already can successfully rotate the camera, but I am still confused about translating the camera. I include the code about how to rotate the camera, Since translating and rotating need to use the lookat function. The homework says translating the camera means that both the eye and the center should be moved with the same amount. I understand I can change the parameters in the lookat function to implement this.

The definition of lookat function is below:

```
Lookat(cameraPos, center, up)
```

```cpp
glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
glm::vec3 center(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

modelViewProjectionMatrix.Perspective(glm::radians(fov), float(width) / float(height), 0.1f, 100.0f);
modelViewProjectionMatrix.LookAt(cameraPos, center, cameraUp);
```

```cpp
void CursorPositionCallback(GLFWwindow* lWindow, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    int state = glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT);

    if (state == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        if (firstMouse)
        {
          lastX = xpos;
          lastY = ypos;
          firstMouse = false;
        }

        float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
        float yoffset = lastY- ypos; 
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;

        yaw += xoffset;
        pitch += yoffset;

        glm::vec3 front;
        front.x = center[0] + 5.0f*cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
        front.y = center[1] + 5.0f*sin(glm::radians(pitch));
        front.z = center[1] + 5.0f*sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
        cameraPos = front;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code already seems to reposition `cameraPos` at a sphere around center, so isn't sufficient to add your displacement to `center`?

Comment: Thank for the suggestions! I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to translate the camera by an offset, then you've to add the same vector (`glm::vec3 offset`) to the camera position (`cameraPos`)  and the camera target (`center`):

```cpp
center    = center    + offset;
cameraPos = cameraPos + offset;
```

When you calculate a new target of the camera (`center`), by a `pitch` and `yaw` angle, then you've to update the up vector (`cameraUp`) of the camera, too:

```cpp
glm::vec3 front(
    cos(glm::radians(pitch)) * cos(glm::radians(yaw)),
    sin(glm::radians(pitch)),
    cos(glm::radians(pitch)) * sin(glm::radians(yaw))
);

glm::vec3 up(
    -sin(glm::radians(pitch)) * cos(glm::radians(yaw)),
     cos(glm::radians(pitch)),
    -sin(glm::radians(pitch)) * sin(glm::radians(yaw))
);

cameraPos = center + front * 5.0f;
cameraUp  = up;
```

To translate the camera along the x axis (from left to right) in viewspace you've to calculate the vector to the right by the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the vector to the target (`front`) and the up vector (`cameraUp` or `up`):

```cpp
glm::vec3 right = glm::cross(front, up);
```

The y axis (from bottom to top) in viewspace, is the up vector.

To translate about the scalars (`float trans_x`) and (`trans_y`), the scaled `right` and `up` vector have to be add to the camera position (`cameraPos`)  and the camera target (`center`):

```cpp
center    = center    + right * trans_x + up * trans_y;
cameraPos = cameraPos + right * trans_x + up * trans_y;
```

Use the manipulated vectors to set the view matrix:

```cpp
modelViewProjectionMatrix.LookAt(cameraPos, center, cameraUp);
```

Comment: Thanks very much!! That's exactly what I need. Your answer is even greater than the explanation provided by my course TA.